# How can I capture and keep data in the same format from Get-ADUser but with a subset of attributes?

Tags: powershell

I've been using `Get-ADUser` to capture data into an object `$users`. This works great for then using `Foreach-Object` and pushing the variable `$user` to `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user`. The cmdlet accepts `$user` and I get data.

As I'm working with a large amount of users - into the 100,000s - I was hoping to pipe the results of `Get-ADUser` though `Select-Object` (including `Samaccountname`) but as soon as I do that, `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user` no longer works. Now, if I use `-ExpandProperty` and `Samaccountname` then the cmdlet once again works but I am stuck with only 1 property.

So my question is this, is there a way to only grab the properties I need from `Get-ADUser` while maintaining the format so that the data can be used by other cmdlets such as `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`?

Finally, I am aware that I can use `$user.Samaccountname` but am trying to see if I can accomplish the same from an object directly.

Edit: To elaborate, the data captured from within $users is used in many other commands. I was using Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership as an example. One other thing to note, when I started using the select option, the amount of time my function ran reduced several fold. The script containing my function went from a few hours to under 30 minutes. I imagine running Get-ADUser many times will once again increase the amount of time my script takes.

Comment: Ok, I'm almost there. Got it to work for 1 user.  <br/>
`$user = get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq "userid"} | {$_.samaccountname,$_.Description,$_.MemberOf,<many more properties>}`  

Then, I can use that object.

`$user | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`
`Compare-object -ReferenceObject $GroupList -DifferenceObject $user.MemberOf`
  
All that is left is doing it for many $users. Is it as simple as adding a 'foreach' before the list of properties I'm capturing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a `foreach`. You can pipe in `Get-ADUser` into `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` directly, and it will iterate through the AD Principals e.g.:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=Staff,DC=contoso,DC=com' -Filter * | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

or even:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=Staff,DC=contoso,DC=com' -Filter *
$users | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

The reason why you can't use a `Select-Object` like:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=Staff,DC=contoso,DC=com' -Filter *
$users | Select-Object SamAccountName | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

Is because the `Select-Object` gives you:

```
PS> $users | Select-Object SamAccountName

SamAccountName
--------------
jsmith
bross
```

An array of objects with only one string Property, SamAccountName. Unfortunately `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` only accepts `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal` as the [Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps#inputs) from the pipeline. Hence, why you can't pass it an array of strings. This means that the only way to make it work is to either pass the AD Principal objects directly, or to, indeed, iterate through them with a `foreach` and directly specifying the users with the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @HAL9256! I've added more info - I'm using the data within $users to query many things - 1 being 'Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership'. I'll have to do some reading but I guess what I want to avoid is creating arrays of strings: using Get-Member I see the array lists the MemberType of Samaccountname as NoteProperty instead of Property. So does that mean if I use 'Select -ExpandProperty' then the output remains Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal?

Comment: Also, is there any other Cmdlets that would keep the data as Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal with the properties I want instead of the default?